# Чтение данных с COM-порта

Tags: qt

У меня проблема с чтением данных с COM-порта в QT. Ниже приведен код, который считывает массив байтов, пересчитывает их и сигнализирует графику, чтобы он их отрисовал. Эта функция запускается в отдельном потоке. В процессе работы (на некоторой итерации цикла) отладчик выдает на строчке

QByteArray data = port->read(1024);

ошибку
HEAP: Free Heap block 30efb8 modified at 30efe0 after it was freed.

и завершает работу.

Ясно, что проблема с памятью, возможно какой-либо объект из основного потока занял ее и не дает с ней работать дальше. Но как избежать этого, непонятно. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.
Среда QT Creator 3.5.1, компилятор MVS2012 x86, отладчик CDB.

```
while(1)
{
    //проверка на выход 
    mutex.lock();
    bool abort = _abort;
    mutex.unlock();

    if (abort) break;

    try
    {
        // читаем данные с порта 
        QByteArray data = port->read(1024);

        qDebug()<<data.length();

        //если пришли - пересчитываем и выводим на график
        if(data.length() > 1023) {

            for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
               if((int)data[i] < 0)
                   osc[i] = level + (255 + (int)data[i]-127)*Amp/(255*del);
               else
                   osc[i] = level + ((int)data[i]-127)*Amp/(255*del);
            }

            emit GraphChanged(x,osc,osc);
        }
    }
    catch(std::exception &e) {
        qDebug()<<e.what();
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте дожидаться момента, когда на порт поступит нужное количество байт, с помощью метода `qint64 QIODevice::bytesAvailable() const`.

Answer (score 2):

У вас из отдельного потока делается попытка управлять гуем. Так делать не надо, это причина странных и непонятных глюков.

Comment: Я не могу вынести это в основной поток, gui будет всегда висеть, так как мне всегда нужно строить точки на графике (GraphChanged)

Comment: вряд ли глюк из за этого, я пробовал убирать строчку  emit GraphChanged(x,osc,osc); - не помогало. Ошибка вываливается именно при чтении порта.

Comment: Ну как минимум одну возможную причину исключили...

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в драйвере COM-порта. Возможно, всё дело в том, что порт открывается в одном потоке, а чтение производится в другом потоке.